# Can't write to file but can write to text

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I created a function `convert()`, which turns a pdf into html and outputs the html as a string.
When I do :

```
print(convert())
```

It works, but when I try to write the result to file:

```
f.write(convert())
```

I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb01' in position 978: character maps to <undefined>
```

In `pycharm` my project encoder is set to UTF-8, and I have a

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

At the beginning of the file. Any ideas on why I get this error?

Comment: Try with `f.write(convert().encode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python version makes a difference.  Here's Python 3.6:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\ufb01')
ﬁ
>>> with open('out.txt','w') as f:
...  f.write('\ufb01')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb01' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

The reason in this case is Python 3.6 on Windows writes to the console with Unicode APIs, so it works nicely.  Opening a file with the default encoding uses code page 1252 on my system, which doesn't support the Unicode character written.  Use an encoding that supports all Unicode characters:

```
>>> with open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
...  f.write('\ufb01')
...
1
```